# How do I pivot a column of interest into multiple columns while merging matching year-ID-covariate rows into one in R?

Tags: r, merge, split

I'm trying to pivot a dataset with many variables and observations in R.

Each row is an ID-Year-Outcome triplet. Each ID-Year-Brightness triplet has one or more corresponding colors that change over time.

| ID | Year | Color | Brightness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | Red | High |
| 1 | 2001 | Blue | High |
| 1 | 2002 | Red | Medium |
| 1 | 2002 | Green | Medium |
| 2 | 2002 | Blue | Low |
| 2 | 2003 | Blue | Medium |
| 2 | 2003 | Yellow | Medium |
| 3 | 2003 | Green | High |
| 3 | 2004 | Orange | Low |

I want to merge each ID-Year-Brightness triplet into a singular row each and spread out the 'Color' variable amongst multiple columns.

I want it to look like this:

| ID | Year | Color 1 | Color 2 | Brightness |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | Red | Blue | High |
| 1 | 2002 | Red | Green | Medium |
| 2 | 2002 | Blue |  | Low |
| 2 | 2003 | Blue | Yellow | Medium |
| 3 | 2003 | Green |  | High |
| 3 | 2004 | Orange |  | Low |

I've tried using pivot_wider and dcast and cSplit and tidyr::spread, but nothing's worked for me so far unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Ben. Please share a reproducible example code rather than a screenshot. So that people could help you out.

Comment: From a pure data management perspective that sort of pivot is not really best practices unless you have a constrained number of values that serve as discrete categories, in which case you could pivot out say 6 columns with color names and a 0 or 1 if there is a value for that id, date and Brightess combination. but otherwise, the value in having long data that is split-apply-combine ready makes more sense. Maybe you could share why you want that shape as you share the code.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::pivot_wider()` can produce your desired output. First we need to add
a column that identifies the row number for each combination of `ID` and `Year`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(ID, Year) |>
  mutate(name = row_number()) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, Year),
              values_from = c(Color, Brightness))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#> # Groups:   ID, Year [6]
#>      ID  Year Color_1 Color_2 Brightness_1 Brightness_2
#>   <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1     1  2001 Red     Blue    High         High        
#> 2     1  2002 Red     Green   Medium       Medium      
#> 3     2  2002 Blue    <NA>    Low          <NA>        
#> 4     2  2003 Blue    Yellow  Medium       Medium      
#> 5     3  2003 Green   <NA>    High         <NA>        
#> 6     3  2004 Orange  <NA>    Low          <NA>
```